# Migrating 100+ repos to gitlab and keeping same repo paths

Tags: migration, gitlab

We have a server with 100+ git repositories (just bare git repos - accessible over ssh)

and there are like 10+ developers who uses these repos

each repo - have remote path like git@myserver.com:project-name

now if I migrate it all to gitlab - the paths will change to

git@myserver.com:**team**/project-name . (! note the team sub-folder)

So every developer and other tools will have to change all those 100+ repo-pathe’s in their .git/config’s

is there way to avoid that - so that when I migrate my repo to gitlab - it’s path should stay the same git@myserver:my-project (without a team subfolder)?

Comment: It is not possible AFAIK